/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-binutils_linux-64.sh:10:47: parameter expansion requires a literal
I am activating a conda environment inside an apptainer and see this weird warnings, and I don't know how to fix that, and what causes it:
apptainer exec container.sif ls
source: /opt/conda/envs/__apptainer__/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-binutils_linux-64.sh:10:47: parameter expansion requires a literal
source: /opt/conda/envs/__apptainer__/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-gcc_linux-64.sh:10:47: parameter expansion requires a literal
source: /opt/conda/envs/__apptainer__/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-gxx_linux-64.sh:10:47: parameter expansion requires a literal
some files to display

It looks like a conda issue.
Apptainer.def
From: condaforge/miniforge3:latest

%files
    environment.yml /environment.yml
    requirements.txt /requirements.txt

%environment
    export PATH="/opt/conda/envs/__apptainer__/bin:$PATH"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/conda/envs/__apptainer__/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    export CPATH="/opt/conda/envs/__apptainer__/include:$CPATH"

%post
    # Install optional packages and programs
    # Need DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive to not get stuck during build
    # Then clean up to keep the container small

    apt-get update && \
        DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Europe/Amsterdam \
        apt-get install -y libopenmpi-dev curl wget vim watch procps ncdu tree build-essential && \
        apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    # Create the __apptainer__ environment. The underscores indicate that the 
    # environment is inside the container. This is a precausion to not mix the 
    # environment up with environments outside the container. This can happen
    # when /home/$USER is mounted inside the container. 

    # Create a new Conda environment with JupyterLab
    mamba env create --quiet --file /environment.yml
    
    # Clean up
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    mamba clean --all -y

    # Now add the script to activate the Conda environment
    echo '. "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"' >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
    echo 'conda activate __apptainer__' >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
    echo 'export SHELL="/bin/bash"' >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT



which gcc version did you install? Either there is something wrong with the activate script that was contained in that package, or the line conda activate __apptainer__ is not executed by the right shell. I don't know anything about apptainer, but since you felt the need to set export SHELL="/bin/bash" I am guessing the lines above it are not neccessarily executed by bash

Ok, maybe they are executed by /bin/sh, thanks for the hint.
